# Collision free, short and unique Integer-only Hashes based on known values

Tags: php, mysql, hash, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to get started with web development by creating a Hotel Reservation System for practice and I have the following problem. I need to create two short, unique, collision free and Integer-only hashes as I have the following requirement:

The number has to be long enough to be believable by a human as it will be sent to them via email as their Booking Code but also short enough to be usable by a human as a 128-Bit Booking Code is weird and it would also be a primary key (unique identifier) for the Bookings Table and Customers Table in the database.

So I need one BookingId and one CustomersID. I know, I could use increment in the MySQL database but I wish to go the rougher route here for learning purposes.

Almost all the Hash functions create longer Hashes with digits and alphabets. But I wish the Hashes to be short and Integer only.

The entire Hash logic would execute in a PHP script right before inserting all the details into the DB using the awesome PDO functionality.

Now, this is the situation:

Each Customer has one unique email address which I know as they insert it in the Booking Form, so I could base the CustomerID on the unique email address. One Customer can only have one CustomerID but he can have multiple unique BookingIDs.

So the CustomerID can be based on the Email Address and the BookingID could be based on the Email and the timestamp.

The difficulty here is to find a Hash function which would result in a 6 Digit collision free Integer only Hash.

How can I generate these two short, unique, collision-free and Integer-only Hashes using PHP?

Comment: How many entries do you expect to have?

Comment: Think about it.... 6 digits and collision free, For today maybe, but what about tomorrow

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams not more than 200 Entries

Comment: @RiggsFolly i could also live with 8 digits but not more than that

Comment: By definition, there is no collision-free (cryptographic) hash function.

Comment: Rather than trying to generate hashes without collision, you should consider the question in another way: generate all IDs you can according to your format/size/whatever. Store the list and randomly pick one when you need it, then remove it from the list.

Comment: or just generate a random id and do a quick query to see if it exists (and iterate until you find one that is available)

Comment: @Pevara it can be fast today, but what about tomorrow?

Comment: `select count(*) from bookings where id = $id` shouldn't take more then a millisecond. And maintaining a list of possible keys just seems like a hassle, and a potential source for bugs. But that is just my opinion offcourse

Comment: so generating a random number and regenerating it if it already exists is fast enough? or would you rather go the hashid way?

Comment: As I said in my answer, I would **not** store random ids in my database and go for the hash id solution. I was merely elaborating on the suggestion @Arcesilas made

Answer (score 4):

Rather then storing your "random ids" in your database, I would just work with a classic auto increment primary key. To the outside world you can encode these id's to make them look like the long integers you desire. And before querying or storing anything in your database you just decode them back to the actual primary key.

As for your customers table, email sounds like a valid option for the primary key, but what if the user decides to change his email address? Or what if you want to support multiple email addresses in the future? I would go for a numeric id for the customers as well, as it is the easy and future proof solution imo.

No need to re-invent the wheel either, I usually use this small library for this:
https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php

Don't let the name fool you by the way, this is strictly speaking an Encrypter, and not a Hasher, since it works in two directions.

It allows you to set a custom alphabet, so your requirement to use only numeric values shouldn't be a problem. Your code would look something like this:

```
$hasher = new Hashids(MY_APP_SALT, 6, '0123456789');
$hashId = $hasher->encode($idFromDb);
$id = $hasher->decode($idFromRequest);
```

**Update:**
To elaborate on your questions in the comments, you could also do

```
$customerId = $hasher->encode($email);
```

And indeed, as long as the parameters you provide on construct of the `$hasher` you'll results remain the same.

The parameters for the constructor are, in order:

- salt, I would put this in a constant or some sort of config value or environment variable, so you can maintain the actual value in a single location
- *minimum* number of characters in the resulting hash. In my experience the actual hash remains quite close to that.
- the allowed characters in the resulting hash.

By the way, I just read about an [alternative library](https://github.com/jenssegers/optimus) in the [docs](http://hashids.org/php/) for if you only want to work with numeric values. No experience with that one, but it may be an even better fit.

Comment: i am not using email as primary key. i just want to create a hash out of the email and then use that as pk.

Comment: My answer still stands, the library I mentioned allows you to encode and decode strings as well (even arrays)

Comment: so MY_APP_SALT is just some random text? and 6 is the minimum length, any option for maximum length? if i decrypt the email hash again using the same salt for the booking id, i guess it would then be pretty much collision free, right?

Comment: I've updated my answer in an attempt answer the questions above, hope it clears things up for you.

Comment: @Zombievirus it's only as collision-free as the uniqueness of an email address goes and that could fail you if someone tries to re-use that same email address and you haven't set that email column to be UNIQUE. This of course, would be when you decrypt it.

Comment: the email is unique as i check before inserting it. the same email does not occur more than once. anyways thanks for all the answers so far. now i know about a few good options. thanx

Comment: The email is unique now, but then a user changes provider and updates his email address. And a year later the ISP makes the old address available again and an entirely new user decides to become your customer. Agreed, that scenario may be a bit far fetched, my point is that  pk based on email is just not a very future proof solution. Just saying though...